# Limit of $\frac{1}{X}\sum^X_n \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$ and$\sqrt[X]{\prod^X_n \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n}$?.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

What is the value of
$$\lim_{X\longrightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{X}\sum^X_{n=1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n$$ 
and
$$\lim_{X\longrightarrow\infty}\sqrt[X]{\prod^X_{n=1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n}.$$

Obviously both have a limit since $(1+n^{-1})^n$ becomes $e$ for $X\longrightarrow \infty$ and all previous values are smaller than $e$.

My first idea: What if the limits are $e$ because there are infinite values of the sum/prod that equal $e$ and therefore the first values of the sum, which are smaller than $e$, do not matter.

Comment: See [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: Mhh doesn't help me

Comment: @f.schneider It helps you just put $a_X=\sum_{n=1}^X(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and $b_X=X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the first: 
  $$
  \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e
  $$
  so by [Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) ("basic" version, no need for the full [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)): 
  $$\frac{1}{X}\sum^X_{n=1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n\xrightarrow[X\to\infty]{} e$$ 
  as well.
- For the second:
  $$
  \ln \sqrt[X]{\prod^X_{n=1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n}
  = \frac{1}{X} \sum^X_{n=1} n \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)
  $$
  and since $n\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$, by Cesàro
  $$
  \ln \sqrt[X]{\prod^X_{n=1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n}
  \xrightarrow[X\to\infty]{} 1
  $$
  so that $
  \sqrt[X]{\prod^X_{n=1} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n}
  = \exp\left(\frac{1}{X} \sum^X_{n=1} n \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)\right)\xrightarrow[X\to\infty]{} e^1 = e.
  $